# How to display 0 minute as '00:00' in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I would like to display 0 minute in `'HH:mm'` format. When I use `moment.duration(0, 'minutes').format('HH:mm')` it returns `'00'` instead of `'00:00'`. Is there a format type in moment.js which displays 0 minute as `'00:00'`?

Comment: `moment.duration(0, 'minutes').format('HH:mm')` throws an error because `format` isn't a valid method of duration. How did you get that working?

Comment: include moment-duration-format.js (https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to use the `moment-duration-format` extension then you need to set the [`trim`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#trim) option to `false`.

> **trim**
>   The default trim behaviour is "large".
>   Largest-magnitude tokens are automatically trimmed when they have no value.
>   To stop trimming altogether, set `{ trim: false }`.

```js
console.log(moment.duration(0, 'minutes').format('hh:mm',{ trim: false }))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.2.2/moment-duration-format.js"></script>
```

This will result in `00:00`

Answer (score 6):

Remove `duration` and simply use `moment().format()` syntax as `moment.duration(0, 'minutes').format('HH:mm')` will give you error of 
`Uncaught TypeError: moment.duration(...).format is not a function`

```js
var res = moment(0, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see, but I would like to use the parameter value as a duration, so there are cases when I pass value other than 0, and there are cases when I pass 0. If I omit duration the next code won't work: `moment(926, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
moment.utc(0).format('HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `format` on `duration` generated. This is the way to do it.

ps. No need for extra `moment-duration-format` library etc

Thanks

```js
var duration = moment(moment.duration("0")).format("HH:mm");
 

console.log(duration)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```